# Use hdfs to save tensorflow checkpoint, events file does not flush until finish?

Tags: tensorflow

Events file size is always 40 unless stop the worker.
    `-rw-r--r--   3 yarn <myname>         40 2016-11-04 12:20 hdfs://default/user/<myname>/.slider/cluster/tfdocker19/checkpoints/events.out.tfevents.1478233223.e1ae78fbc2bb`

BTW, i use the tensorBoard to display. It could work, but could not update unless restart it.
    `tensorboard --logdir hdfs://default/user/<myname>/.slider/cluster/tfdocker19/checkpoints`

Comment: Could this be a general HDFS reluctance to flush? Do you see this behavior on a local file system?

Comment: Events could be flushed to the local filesystem as expected. And tensorBoard could reload events from the local filesystem and refresh webUI automaticly.